# Set the level and order of an object in list

Tags: r

I want create a list of objects that includes a dataframe `df`, where `df` is added as the first object to an existing list. In the example, `list_1` is the existing list, and I want to create list of length 3 where `df` is the first object. Here's what I tried: For `list_2`, I used `list()` and got a list `length=2`. In `list_4`, `append()` just added the objects in `list_1` to `df`. In the final attempt, I created a list of `length=3`, but with `df` at the end. It seems like there's something really obvious that I'm missing?

```
df <- tibble(x=c("a","b","c"),
             y=c("d","e","f"))
list_1 <- list("one" = 1,
               "chr" = "string")
list_2 <- list(df, list_1)
list_4 <- append(df, list_1)

list_1$df <- df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `c` function which also handles `list` object type.

> The default method combines its arguments to form a vector. All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value

Putting the dataframe in a list protects it from being split into its columns :

```
c(list_1,df = list(df))
$one
[1] 1

$chr
[1] "string"

$df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     d    
2 b     e    
3 c     f 

c(df = list(df),list_1)
$df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     d    
2 b     e    
3 c     f    

$one
[1] 1

$chr
[1] "string"
```